# Request Delete record from Django API by ID using python requests

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I am testing functionality of my first Django API

currently i am able to do GET and POST by using requests

I am stuck on trying to make delete request by ID

This is my REST_FRAMEWORK API CODE

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'Delete'])

def ShopList(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Shop.objects.all()
        serializer = ShopSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ShopSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        shop = Shop.objects.get(id=id)
        shop.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

In request.method == 'DELETE' i have tried

```
elif request.method == 'DELETE':
    shop = Shop.objects.all()
    shop.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Which deletes everything

How can I make a DELETE request which can delete records by given id or others attributes?

My intuition lies on

```
shop = Shop.objects.get(id = id)
```

Which gets the objects by id but my implementation is probably wrong.

Here is my request code

```
import requests
import json
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/'
payload = {'Establishment' : 'MacDonalds', 'Address' : '114/5 Albert St.', 'Suburb' : 'Wellington', 'Postcode' : '8218', 'State' : 'No Data', 'Establishment_Type' : 'Home'}
requests.delete(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

The requests method above aims to search for all similar records given in the dictionary and delete it. However, objects.all() seems to delete everything

My DELETE request is similar to this SQL function

```
DELETE FROM SHOP
WHERE id = 12;
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

add **Id** into payload and change to shop = Shop.objects.get(id = request.data.id)